# How to add notifications to the InfoCenter?

Tags: c#, windows-10

How do I add notifications to the InfoCenter? To find an answer, I need to know which terms to look for.

Comment: Isn't it called the "Action Center"? That could be part of your problem... :-) They are also called "toasts", as in "toast notification".

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/ should help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great guide, hope it helps:
http://www.howtogeek.com/223503/how-to-use-and-configure-the-new-notification-center-in-windows-10/

Comment: That creates a toast, but it does not add anything to the info center(called action center in the english version of windows)